# Channels ---> Filters: Direct Relationship?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

If you have 32 input channels and 16 filters, do channels 17-32 get dropped? Or do 16 random channels get dropped or do all of the channels pass on? What if there are more filters than input channels?

I read that the first filter/kernel convolves with the corresponding channel in a convolution layer  --first channel with first filter, second channels with second filter, ect -- but **what happens if the number of input channels is not equal to the number of filters?**
(Source: http://machinelearninguru.com/computer_vision/basics/convolution/convolution_layer.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you have 32 input channels, then the input has shape (samples, W, H, 32). then your 16 filters would have shape (F_W, F_H, 32). As you see, each of the filters has 32 channels, so when you perform convolution it is compatible since the number of channels in the filter equal the number of channels in the input.

And then since there are 16 filters, after doing all 16 convolutions, you will have a 16 channel output feature map, since each convolution operation produces one feature map.

Comment: thank you! so just to confirm, the number of filters is independent of the number of input channels, and every input channel is filtered?

Comment: @c19ut Yes, that's what my answer says.

Comment: Then if all filters are initialized to the same values, what is the point of having multiple filters in the same level? Won't they all be carrying the same information? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @c19ut They aren't initialized to the same values.

Answer (score 1):

Here input channel means depth. Like in RGB image we have 3 channels.
what these 16 filter do is, they compute 16 different feature maps(FM) and these 16 FM will be input for next layer.

[image: Here we have image with 3 channels and we have 2 filters now after applying these filters you'll get 2 different FM and by combining them you'll get a output]

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, this is not true at all. Number of filters doesn't have to be equal to the number of input channels.

Comment: hi, sorry could you please explain further? someone made an example CNN model with keras (source: https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-convolutional-neural-network-cnn-in-keras-329fbbadc5f5) where the number of channels is 1 and the number of filters is 64. model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation=’relu’, input_shape=(28,28,1)))                                           What is happening in this example? sorry for the trouble

Comment: Here you'll get 64 different Feature Maps. please follow the image i posted.